# How to pass a javascript return value to spring path variable

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf, dropdown, path-variables

My goal is grab the return value of a javascript function an then pass as spring path variable

I tried to do this code:

- The dropdown,  populate data that the user want to pick up

  ```
              <label for="cust">Select a customer</label> <select
                  id="cust" class="form-control">
                  <option  th:each="customer: ${customers}"
                      th:value="${customer.id}" th:utext="${customer.name}" />
              </select>
  ```
- The script, It get the selected customer

  ```
  <script>
  function getSelected() {
      var cust_id = document.getElementById("cust").value;
      return cust_id;
  }</script>
  ```
- The button, This is where I been lost. How to send this cust_id to my controller with this th:href?

  ```
                  <input type="button" class="button form-control btn-primary"
                  th:value="Next" onclick="getSelected()" th:href="@{/locate/{id}(id=${cust_id})}">
  ```

My question is how to pass cust_id as parameter? 
If there is a easiest way to do this, please show me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation. This is how I implemented it:

```
$('#cust').bind('change',function() {
    var custid = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    alert("You have selected the Customer with id - " + custid);
    window.location = '/myAppURL?pareaName='+ $(this).val();
    });
```

It means to pick a value from a select (option) I had to bind it with the change event (I used JQuery). Not sure if it fits your "exact" requirement but hoping you got the idea.

Comment: Can you please appreciate by accepting the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Yes of course, your snipped helped me out. I kept the assignation variable cust_id of my script, because it is able to retrieve the user selection and then I've used the windows.location object of your snippet and I've concatenated to  the result of my cust_id. It worked fine, thank you Ajay.